# AppleScript iTunes: Select a file by location?

Tags: applescript, itunes

I want to select one or more tracks in my iTunes by their absolute location from the command line, so like:

```
osascript Refresh.scpt /Users/elliot/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/Apocalyptica/Apocalyptica/06\ Fisheye.m4a /Users/elliot/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/Apocalyptica/Apocalyptica/10\ Ruska.m4a
```

After the tracks are selected I can refresh their tags... or maybe their is another way to tell iTunes externally to refresh specific tracks?

Answer (score -1):

You will find useful scripts and tools on [this page](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/).